# UIkit 3x Slideshow the size of the images are 0

Tags: slideshow, getuikit

i have a problem with the Slideshow component by UIkit:
the site of the images are 0 and doesn't show images - with without uk-cover they show the first images, but the next images are Style="width:0;height:0"…

here the code

```
<div class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle uk-slideshow" uk-slideshow="animation: fade">
  <ul class="uk-slideshow-items" uk-lightbox="animation: fade">
      <li class="uk-active uk-transition-active" style="z-index: -1;">
        <a href="#"><img src="imag1.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="image2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </li>
   </ul>

   <div class="uk-position-relative uk-position-small uk-visible-toggle uk-light uk-slider uk-slider-container" uk-slider="">
     <ul class="uk-slider-items uk-child-width-1-2 uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-child-width-1-4@m">
       <li uk-slideshow-item="0" class="uk-transition-active uk-active">
         <a href="#"><img src="image1.jpg"></a>
       </li>
       <li uk-slideshow-item="1" >
         <a href="#"><img src="image2.jpg" alt=""></a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please rewrite your question as I wanted to help, but I simply don't understand what your question is about

Answer (score 0):

Add the uk-position-cover class.

```
<a class="uk-position-cover" href="image2.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?  The code in your answer should be supplemented with an explanation of how it answers the question.  Especially considering the question is a little bit unclear still, it would be good to understand how you are helping, and what aspect of the problem you are addressing.

Answer (score 0):

Slideshow component displays images as background images.
Therefore, slideshow container must have height property.

```
        <div class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle uk-light" tabindex="-1"
        uk-slideshow="animation: slide; autoplay: true; autoplay-interval: 3000">

        <ul class="uk-slideshow-items" uk-height-viewport="offset-top: true;">

uk-height-viewport="offset-top: true" --> set min-height as 100vh or less according to viewport and elements (without fixed or absolute positionned) on top of slideshow.
```

Here is the [pen](https://codepen.io/e2a4/pen/abJqRVY) slideshow with data-srcset. You can add images url seperately for mobile and desktop.